Google Cloud Functions: ' "build": missing main.py and GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SOURCE not specified '
GCP displays the following error wherein it is unable to read the main.py file even though I have included it.
I have simply copied the inline demo function given in the gcp cloud function and created a file. Now when trying to upload the zip file, this error is given when deploying the function.
Step #2 - "build": missing main.py and GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SOURCE not specified. Either create the function in main.py or specify GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SOURCE to point to the file that contains the function
file hierarchy:
gcp/
--main.py
--requirements.txt
main.py file:
import functions_framework

@functions_framework.http
def hello_http(request):
    """HTTP Cloud Function.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): The request object.
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#incoming-request-data>
    Returns:
        The response text, or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using `make_response`
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.make_response>.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    request_args = request.args

    if request_json and 'name' in request_json:
        name = request_json['name']
    elif request_args and 'name' in request_args:
        name = request_args['name']
    else:
        name = 'World'
    return 'Hello {}!'.format(name)

reqirements.txt file:
functions-framework==3.*


What command to you run, and in which directory?

I am just trying to deploy it in gcp cloud function. The error shown is received when i try to deploy and run the function on gcp.

Directly on the console?

Using the gcp gui, not on the console

I'm sure the folder is an issue. Remove it and put all the file at the root level
